# could not find java in JAVA_HOME at /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-1.el8_3.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm getting an error when setting the $JAVA_HOME variable on my CentOS system.

Not sure what causing Java to be unrecognized, this is a new VM provisioned with no issues observed.

```
[Khurum@localhost bin]$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for Khurum:

There is 1 program that provides 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-1.el8_3.x86_64/jre/bin/java)

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: ^C
[Khurum@localhost bin]$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-1.el8_3.x86_64/jre/bin/java
[Khurum@localhost bin]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-1.el8_3.x86_64/jre/bin/java
[Khurum@localhost bin]$ ./elasticsearch
could not find java in JAVA_HOME at /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-1.el8_3.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting your JAVA_HOME incorrectly; it should point to the folder, not the Java executable:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-1.el8_3.x86_64/
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems the issue is that I didn't point to the right path and forgotten a directory in my syntax. Here's the command: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-1.el8_3.x86_64/jre

Comment: If you think this answers the question you can accept it by clicking on the tick next to the answer. By the way, you can also specify the above without the `jre/` at the end.